# Bokeh stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, bokeh

I want to do a stacked bar chart in jupyter using pandas and bokeh.
I have 3 columns:['Feedstuff','Month','Price'].
I want to have Price on x axis, Name of each Feedstuff on y axis, and bars stacked by months. 
My data looks like this:

```
data=[
['feed_wheat','Jan',138.24],
['feed_wheat','Dec',141.84],
['wheat_feed','Jan',106.45], ], 
columns=['Feedstuff','Month','Price']
```

My plotting code

```
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(T_M_11)
fs=source.data['Feedstuff'].tolist()
mt=source.data['Month'].tolist()
pr=source.data['Price'].tolist()
colors = ["#A5D6F3", "#B7D8EB", "#72A2D0","#252825","#505D66","#71A5D8","#2A5581","#202E26","#3D545F",
         "#20364C","#6E9CD5","#3F64B4"]
data = {
    'Feedstuff' : fs,
     pr : mt
}


p = figure(x_range=fs, plot_height=250, title="Средняя цена за месяцы за 1 единицу корма (Ł/ton), в фунт стерлингов",
           toolbar_location=None,tools="hover", tooltips="$name @fs: @$name")

p.vbar_stack(mt, x='Feedstuff', width=0.9, color=colors,source=data,
             legend_label=mt)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

This is how error looks like:

```
> BokehJS 1.4.0 successfully loaded.
>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-361-b751cfb4a157> in <module>
>     9 data = {
>     10     'Feedstuff' : fs,
>---> 11      pr : mt
>     12 }
> 13 
>TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Unfortunately my plotting code doesn't work. Could you please help me.

Comment: All the keys in `data` must be strings (names of dat columns). What are you trying to accomplish by making `pr` a key? Python itself will not allow lists as dictionary keys because they are mutable.

Comment: I want to display prices on y axis, they are numerical. The longer the bar the higher the price. I have different feedstuff. And each feedstuff has different prices in each month.  On x axis I want to have the name of each feedstuff,(that is the main title and subtitle is month). Each Feedstuff will have 12 small bars each one representing price of each month for separeted feedstuff. That is what I want to get. ^-^

Comment: Like y axis : Price; x axis : Jan: prices of each stuff in january.

Comment: Have you compared what you need to this minimal similar example in the docs? https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#stacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data DataFrame, this worked for me...

```
data_aux=pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(data['Feedstuff'].unique(), data['Month'].unique())).T.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['Feedstuff', 'Month']).merge(data, on=['Feedstuff',  'Month'], how='left').fillna(0)
data2 = {'Feedstuff' : data_aux['Feedstuff'].unique()}
data2.update(data_aux.groupby(['Month'])['Price'].apply(list).to_dict())

p= figure(y_range=fs, x_range=(0, 1000))

p.hbar_stack(mt, y='Feedstuff', height=0.9, color= ["#A5D6F3", "#B7D8EB"], source=ColumnDataSource(data2))
show(p)
```